# Datatables server-side with defered pages

Tags: pagination, datatables, server-side

On a server-side table, I want to initialize a table with the first 3 pages. The deferLoading property allows you to skip the loading of the first elements, before doing a Ajax call. But I'm not being able to paginate those already loaded elements.

When you get to the page where the table is loaded, you want to display some set of results. As said, you can load the first 10 records and doing a "normal pagination", but we'd like to load the first 30 records, but still display it with 10 elements per page. If the user navigated to the second page, the data would already be loaded and the page would be displayed as-in client-side pagination. The same for the third page. If the user reached the 4th page, then it would trigger the Ajax call to get the server-side loaded data.

Comment: Can I ask why you want to do this?

Comment: Imagine a scenario where the (computational / memory / time) cost of doing a query for the data is very high, but whether you retrieve 10 or 1000 records it's more or less the same. With basic Ajax loading, you'll do a (costly) query for every page. If you could immediately load 5 pages, and just start querying the server on the 6th page (most users won't get there), it would increase the user experience.